# Как русифицировать шаблон сайта?

Tags: кодировка, utf-8

Добрый день, уважаемые специалисты. Моя знакомая попросила сделать ей страничку используя вот [этот шаблончик](http://freehtml5templates.com/downloads/free/elegantpress/).
Однако, я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: шаблон не русифицирован. Как можно его сделать русским? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я имею в виду не словарики и переводить, а чтобы поддерживались русские кодировки. Знаю, что это можно делать через мета данные, однако у меня это не вышло по непонятным для меня причинам.

Comment: Что вы пробовали и что у вас не получалось? Понятия "русифицировать шаблон" не существует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм, как не странно, старый добрый `.htaccess` оказался полезен. И строка `AddDefaultCharset utf8` решила проблему.